# Фон дендрограммы в Python заливается серым цветом

Tags: python, анализ-данных, визуализация, scipy

Мой код:

```
credit_df = pd.read_csv('CC_GENERAL.csv')
print('Dimension of array:{}'.format(credit_df.shape))
#Dimension of array:(8950, 18)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=0.95)
credit_pca = pca.fit_transform(credit_df)
credit_pca = np.matrix(credit_pca)

credit_pca = pd.DataFrame(credit_pca)

import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as shc
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))  
plt.title("Dendrogram")  
dend = shc.dendrogram(shc.linkage(credit_pca, method='ward'))
plt.axhline(y=350, color='r', linestyle='--')
```

Выводится дендрограмма с серым фоном вместо белого:

[image: Дендрограмма]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать фон белым?

Ссылка на данные: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1swoSGw9UkRJ1Hp9mhYVhJzDYPJIdjDcA/view?usp=sharing

Ссылка на блокнот Jupiter в Google Collab:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ipwLJNRRz7_a0VYw0WpqwofIgTx8WuuR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: А можно узнать, что такое `credit_pca`, и при возможности добавить его в текст вопроса? (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1372003/edit)

Comment: Добавила часть кода!

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ещё добавить csv-файл, чтобы можно было напрямую просмотреть?

Comment: Я прикрепила ссылки на полный текст кода и данные (на гугл диске)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле это не серый фон, а линии сетки графика, которые — ввиду того, что сам график достаточно громоздок, но мал по размерам — слипаются в серый фон.

Чтобы убрать эту сетку (а следовательно, и "серый фон"), нужно отключить сетку через метод `plt.grid(visible=False)` (подробнее о grid [здесь](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html)). После этого сетка графика пропадёт, как и "серый фон", и у Вас останется лишь график дендрограммы на белом фоне.

```py
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as shc
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))  
plt.title("Dendrogram")  
dend = shc.dendrogram(shc.linkage(credit_pca, method='ward'))
plt.axhline(y=350, color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.grid(visible=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: без сетки]

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!